# Index or size is negative or greater than allowed amount (non-negative indices)

Tags: javascript, loops

While using Firefox, I keep getting the error described in the subject line for this block of code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
{
    var j = rows.length - 1;
    while(j--)
    {                   
        if(hideDP && tables[i].innerHTML.indexOf(">D<") != -1)
        {   
            if(!platTag && !soulSilverTag && pearlTag)
            {
                tables[i].deleteRow(j);//ERROR IS ON THIS LINE
            }
        }

    }//end while loop (rows)
}//end for loop (tables)
```

I suspect that this error is because I'm somewhat new to making reverse loops, but I specifically made a reverse loop in this instance because it made deleting rows from a table easier. Note also that j is something like 24 and i is 0, so they're non-negative. Could someone shed some light on this for me?

**EDIT :** The full code [can be found here](http://pastebin.com/zNLSm3vP).

Comment: On which line is the error triggered?

Comment: It's about 6 lines from the end, actually. I commented "ERROR ON THIS LINE" to try and make it stand out. I included the other code just for context.

Comment: I don't see where i is defined anywhere in the code you posted, so presumably the value of i is where the problem is.

Comment: does it say what line the error occurs on ? that might give us all a better clue

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? I edited the OP to make the code easier to see at-a-glance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly working off of the currently posted code, here are the issues I see:

1. The posted code looks incomplete.  Where is `rows` being initialized?  This could cause the stated error.
2. Given `while(j--)`;   The `var j = rows.length - 1;` line is incorrect.  That is, *unless* you know that the last row will never need deleting.  But if that is the case, then comment the code to make it clear.

   For example, if there were 4 rows, the current code initializes `j` to 3, but because of the location of the `--` operator, the inside of the loop sees: 2, 1, 0.   For the code as shown, use `var j = rows.length;` or add a comment to show that the logic is deliberate.
3. The 2 `if()` statements do not depend on `j` at all!  (At least as the code is posted here.)  If this is true, then move the conditionals outside of the `j` loop.
4. Consider posting the full, unedited, code. Or linking to it on a site like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

---

---

### Update for full script, now that it's been linked to:

Scanning the complete code, it looks like `tables[i].deleteRow(j);` can be called multiple times for the same row.

The easy solution, that should be done anyway, is to add a [`continue`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp) statement after each row delete.

For extra credit, reanalyze and simplify the flag and `if` logic too. :)

---

---

### Update for target page, now that it's been linked to:

Examining the target page, the tables being looped by this script contain nested tables.

That throws off the row count in this line:
`var rows = tables[i].getElementsByTagName("tr");`

Sometimes making it seem like table[i] has more rows than it really directly owns.

Solution, use the built in rows array; so the line becomes:
`var rows = tables[i].rows;`

~~~~
While examining  the script relative to the target page, a few other issues seemed apparent:

1. It's not best to loop through all tables.  Target just the ones you need.  So this:
   `tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");`

   Should be changed to:

   ```
   var tables = document.querySelectorAll ("div.KonaBody > table.roundy");
   ```

   ...which will select just the 4 payload tables, and not their subtables or the other tables scattered about.
2. By fine-tuning the initial table selection, the following, problamatic, test is not needed:

   ```
   if(tables[i].getAttribute("style").indexOf("border: 3px solid") != -1)
   ```
3. Missing `var` in front of the `majorSections` initialization.

Comment: Good idea, Brock. True, I did prune out a fair bit of the function to make it less overwhelming. Here's a link to the [script as-is on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zNLSm3vP).

Comment: Yes, it seems I forgot the continues. The extra "else if" statements in each of the conditionals are mainly for debugging, and I'll take them out once I get this all ironed out. Unfortunately, after adding all of the continues, I'm still getting the same error. If you're interested in seeing where this would be useful, look at [this page](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ponyta_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29/Generation_IV_learnset#By_leveling_up) and see how messy the learnset table looks. That's also the page I'm using for testing. [Script I'm using](http://pastebin.com/BtMkUERE).

Comment: You're making me work for this one. :)   Anyway, the code made an assumption that's not valid given the target page.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this, Brock. It's a really good thing to now know about the querySelectorAll, because it makes filtering out nested tables a lot easier. I take it the ">" symbol is indicative of child elements? So if I understand correctly, the new assignment for var tables is telling the document to select all divs with the class "KonaBody" that have child table elements with the class "roundy". Am I right?

Comment: You're welcome.  And, yes, `>` is the [child (direct descendant) selector](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_child.htm).

Answer (score 0):

That error will also be generated if j is >= to the amount of rows in the table, but I'm not seeing the exact problem.